# Sorting and secondary sorting in java using Coamparable interface

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

I have class called *Order* where  I have getter and setter methods for *OrderID* and *produstID* field.

1) I want to get sort *orderID* in asending order and corresponding *productID* in desending order. So I used *Comparable interface* and *compareTo* methods to do that.I'm able to sort *orderID* but corresponding productID's are not sorted in descending order(secondary sorting).

Please let me know how can i do that.

Code i have used :

```
   @Override
public int compareTo(Order ord)
{
    double orderId1 = ((Order) ord).getOrderId();
    return (int) (this.orderId - orderId1);
    //return orderId.equals(ord.orderId);
}
```

2) I wanted to search based on *orderID* and want to get corresponding *productid*'s.

Here I'm using hard coded data.

My data lokks like this:

Order data:

```
orderID  productID
1001        22
1003        33
1001         33
```

Desired output for soring is :

```
 orderID  productID
1001        33
1001        22
1003        33
```

Comment: Show the code where you use the comparator to sort the collection.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work:

```
public int compareTo(Order ord)
{
    if (this.orderId == ord.getOrderId()){
       return (int) (ord.getProductId() - this.productId);
    }
    return  this.orderId - ord.getOrderId();
}
```

if have to compare the productId only if the is orderId  equals.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use built-in functions for comparing.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Order o) {
    int d = Double.compare(this.getOrderId(), o.getOrderId());
    if (d == 0) {
        d = Double.compare(o.getProductId(), this.getProductId());
    }
    return d;
}
```

But I don't really think that your `orderId` and `productId` should be of `double` type. Better have them as `int`. If you change to `int` then still use the built-in comparators, just change to `Integer.compare(x,y)`.

Comment: Hey thank you so much. Sorting and secondary sorting is working fine. But how can i search based on orderId and get corresponding productID. Here if i create method called SearchByOrderid(), then when i pass orderid as 1001, then i should get all the prodid's attached to that. How can i do this.

Comment: @shree11 That depends on what kind of collection you are using. Can you update your question with that information?

Comment: Here i'm using `List<Order> OrderList= new ArrayList<Order>();`. Here have created method called SearchByOrderID(Order id); So whenever i pass the OrderID, i should get all the productID's attached to it.

Comment: @shree11 I think you'll need to use a TreeMap instead and then you can use `TreeMap#subMap` to get a partial view of the TreeMap with all the objects you are interrested in.

Comment: Can i do like this : `public Order1 SearchByOrderID(int o) {
  //logic for search
 }` and main method call SerachByOrderID. But i do not know how to do it

Comment: Hi, I'm able to search based on OrderID  as below : `public Order SearchByOrderID(List<Order> OrderList,Integer orderId) {
  Order1 result = null;
  
  for (Order order1 : OrderList) {
   
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < OrderList.size(); i++) {
   if (OrderList.get(i).getOrderId() == orderId) {
    result = OrderList.get(i);
   }
  }
  return result;
 }`  . But i wanted to use HASH MAP for searching instead of going for above approach. So how can I do it ?

Comment: @shree11 To get more attention to this question you should create a new one with only the last part, how to get all productIds from a sorted list. This will be a too long thread for these two different questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo( Order ord )
{
    if( this.orderId != ord.getOrderId() )
    {
        return Double.compare( this.orderId, ord.getOrderId() );
    }
    return Double.compare( ord.getProductId(), this.productId );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample with your data that orders the items

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class TestOrder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<OrderProduct> myList=new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add(new OrderProduct(22, 1001));
        myList.add(new OrderProduct(33, 1003));
        myList.add(new OrderProduct(33, 1001));
        Collections.sort(myList);
        for (OrderProduct op : myList) {
            System.out.println(op.getOrderId() + " " + op.productId);
        }

    }

    private static class OrderProduct implements Comparable<OrderProduct>{
        private int productId;
        private int orderId;

        public OrderProduct(int productId, int orderId) {
            super();
            this.productId = productId;
            this.orderId = orderId;
        }


        public int getProductId() {
            return productId;
        }
        public int getOrderId() {
            return orderId;
        }


        @Override
        public int compareTo(OrderProduct o) {
            if (o==null) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (orderId==o.orderId) {
                return o.productId-productId;
            }
            return orderId-o.orderId;
        }
    }

}
```